# In non-semisimple category $M \otimes N \not\cong N \otimes M$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory, quantum-groups

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the category of all finite dimensional $U_q(\hat{g})$-modules, where $U_q(\hat{g})$ is an quantum affine algebra. In the category $\mathcal{C}$, usually $M \otimes N \not\cong N \otimes M$ ($M,N$ are two finite dimensional $U_q(\hat{g})$-modules)? Thank you very much.

Comment: What is the monoidal structure here?

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: i guess OP implies the usual tensor product of modules.

Comment: But what do you mean "usually" ? are you interested in either examples or counterexamples ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in general $M\otimes N$ is not isomorphic to $N\otimes M$ in $\mathcal{C}$, because the category $\mathcal{C}$ is not braided - see the answers [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/314/are-there-interesting-monoidal-structures-on-representations-of-quantum-affine-a).